# How can I make a typesafe generic function

Tags: typescript

I think this is possible but I'm having trouble searching for the right keywords.
I have a method that is used to set multiple properties of an object and I'd like it type safe.

```
interface ICase {
  caseDetails: ICaseDetails;
  observations: IObservations;
}
interface ICaseDetails {
  a: string;
}
interface IObservations {
  b: number;
}

const updateCasePart = (state: ICase, payload: any, propName: keyof ICase) => { 
  state[propName] = payload
}
```

Is there a way I can type payload so that a calling function would be limited to the correct payload types?  I know I could do `payload: ICaseDetails | IObservations` but I was hoping for something like `payload: typeof keyof ICase`

Comment: What is `ICaseDetails` and `IObservations`?  Ideally the code would be a [mre] with no undefined/undeclared types and values

Comment: Presumably you're looking like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0bQRw).  Does that meet your needs?   Note that the title refers to a "generic method" but the word "method" doesn't really apply here (or is ambiguous); could you [edit] it to "function"?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thanks!  If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your title suggests, you should make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) as follows:

```
const updateCasePart = <K extends keyof ICase>(
  state: ICase, payload: ICase[K], propName: K
) => { state[propName] = payload }
```

Instead of [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the `propName` parameter as being of type `keyof ICase` (equivalent to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"caseDetails" | "observations"`), we annotate it as being of the generic type `K` which has been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof ICase`.  This allows `propName` to be *more specific* than `keyof ICase`.  For example, if you pass in `"caseDetails"` as `propName`, the compiler will infer that `K` is the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"caseDetails"`.

And note that the type of `payload` is the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `ICase[K]`, meaning the type of the property of `ICase` at a key of type `K`.  So if `K` is `"caseDetails"`, then `ICase[K]` is `ICaseDetails`.  This (mostly) ensures that the value you pass in for `payload` will be appropriate.

The assignment `state[propName] = payload` type checks because the compiler sees both sides of the assignment as being of the identical generic type `ICase[K]`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
declare const caseDetails: ICaseDetails;
declare const observations: IObservations;
declare const state: ICase;

updateCasePart(state, caseDetails, "caseDetails"); // okay
updateCasePart(state, caseDetails, "observations"); // error!
// -----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'ICaseDetails' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IObservations'.
updateCasePart(state, observations, "observations"); // okay
```

Looks good.  The compiler allows valid calls and (mostly) disallows invalid calls.

---

Okay I keep saying "mostly".  There's a type safety hole with generics involving unions; if for some strange reason you pass in a `propName` argument whose type is a union of key types, then `K` will be inferred as that union, and `ICase[K]` will also be a union, meaning it's possible for bad calls to be allowed:

```
updateCasePart(state, caseDetails,
  Math.random() < 0.99 ? "observations" : "caseDetails"
); // okay?!
```

There's no error in the above, but there's a 99% chance you've passed in `"observations"` as `propName` with an `ICaseDetails` as `payload`.

If it really matters, it's possible to start rewriting `updateCasePart` to make such things less likely... but since [TypeScript isn't fully type safe](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), you can't really prevent every possible unsafe operation, and there are diminishing returns with added efforts.

For most purposes, a generic function like the above provides adequate safety and usability, and so I won't digress here further by detailing possible excursions down the endless and increasingly treacherous endless road toward pure soundness.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGE4GcUG8BQyyC2EAIhGHMADZYBcamOFVtWA3IcgPYBGOKADc4YYDxAM0AeQHQRYiZ3wBffPlCRYiFBlKtqdZASJxGWMFFABzLms3R4SGXOGjxk49z6MQAVwBbPmg7dQQlMGQ-AAcAE1EIZggABTgoSIBeZAAeAGlkCAAPSBBYrGQAawgATx4YJlIAPgAKbgsExj0cABpkaLhqmh44WM6kgG1cgF1e6KgeaIA5OACIRlz8AEpkDMbjZHbIcbmF5dWpnb6BoZHkNXxYiAQaNJRwyUiSFkpDKS7yH7sLiPZ6vYgRXiuBQeP6yQTQpTAp4vKBvCGHNYNHBcfAxeKQJKpdLNDG9L4Ath0XoAInJBnY1M2HGQAHoWbwKgNcXEEoS0mASVRIGT9ICqchqfx4e4lIzmWyClB5lAAIT4BUAWi12p1uq1ewAfkbjSaDer2QBBKDWQIQcC8epgarRFAAcn+9LoruQwHKIB4kWwWGA1hAcD4NBQYB4VygK0o0AdyCdLuQ7rh8hlkldADpufjEqQiQLSZDpYpJDSpZmK1g5az2TxOdV1HjeUX+YKEiLvpSsN1uABZUQACxzcdKPACzW22WQAAYcwBOJfIAD8Eurblr1OQjFpor71K28sbzbXavwYdWWH6zlQIAQqNIsXQU+ikcKwCdXm4KZQVrWFg2TJAUxR2mUlQ1HUWIQHsWS4Mgkw+iAyDJFMjDHNcwyjLBkwzH08xLPG6wXCo4zodw7wWFEPIEh26SXCBYElJBVS1PU-wtNwRAYmMpC9DmQlYYMOGzERZwQBhyCAcBySNNw2y7PsGLHBJ8YXFk-Sibc9xECCKJoh8xCHr8-G9r8XD6ciYLUZEW4IpInQZtuMJWcgBm2eiQqYv8OJEG29E4MWXbCiZFnsDSdJinWTINhyXIBXRhbBZ2pbRX2VZQlmsWnoqyoqkQ6hJQWfLEulpmRTxyDDmAY4TrEU4zjkC7LquG6StlO57hKGW-MeRBxQq0AFeoqhAA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz I appreciate the extra nuance you posted here.
I think in my case the addition of typing the incoming payload will safeguard 'super good enough'